# Can't get default page to work with iis 7

Tags: iis

How can I have my website [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) point to [www.example.com/myProject.test/](http://www.example.com/myProject.test) in IIS?

I tried adding "myProject.test" as a default document, but it doesn't work. The type is "local" instead of "inherited".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up pointing the IIS directly to  [www.example.com/myProject.test/](http://%20www.example.com/myProject.test/) and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you can do this with either HTTP Redirect or with URL Rewrite modules.

URL REWRITE: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

HTTP Redirection: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't think that fits my case, I simply need to have my own path as a default page but for some reason I can't set it up in IIS.

Comment: It fits your case, just give it a try.

Comment: Isn't there any simpler way to do it? Through IIS?

Comment: Those two ways will take you less than 2 minutes.

Comment: I just tried the http redirection and I got a 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' error.

Comment: Perfect, start a new question - The ask why you are getting that error and show a screenshot or the information in the config file related to to the changed you made.